# c++ Polymorphism without a Heap

Tags: c++, embedded

I am starting with c++ embedded development and was searching for to implement the factory pattern without using the heap. I found this post https://barrgroup.com/embedded-systems/how-to/polymorphism-no-heap-memory where it shows how to do polymorphism without the heap. So I could use it to to implement the factory pattern.

After reading this post I realized that I could implement the same thing only using the "placement new", my code works.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <new>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std; 

enum VehicleType { 
    VT_TwoWheeler, VT_ThreeWheeler
}; 

char buff[20];

class Vehicle { 
public: 
    virtual void printVehicle()=0; 
}; 

class TwoWheeler : public Vehicle { 
public: 
    TwoWheeler() {
        assert(sizeof(*this) <= sizeof(buff));  
    }
    void printVehicle() { 
        cout << "I am two wheeler" << endl; 
    } 
}; 
class ThreeWheeler : public Vehicle { 
public: 
    ThreeWheeler() {
        assert(sizeof(*this) <= sizeof(buff));  
    }
    void printVehicle() { 
        cout << "I am three wheeler" << endl; 
    } 
}; 

Vehicle *v1ptr;

// Driver program 
int main() { 
    VehicleType type = VT_ThreeWheeler; 
    if (type == VT_TwoWheeler) 
        v1ptr = new(buff) TwoWheeler;
    else if (type == VT_ThreeWheeler) 
        v1ptr = new(buff) ThreeWheeler;
    v1ptr->printVehicle(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

it correctly print: I am three wheeler

Does anybody see any pitfall on this implementation?
Thanks

Comment: _"Does anybody see any pitfall on this implementation?"_ No, not at a 1st glance. Using placement new is perfectly fine. Just ensure that your `buff` is providing enough space to allocate your classes.

Comment: Thanks @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @Gust If you want a thourough review for already working code I'd recommend to ask at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Great @πάνταῥεῖ I will check that

Comment: You'll probably forget to destruct your object at some point doing it this way though.

Comment: Fun fact: You almost never see it happen outside of academic research, but C++ doesn't require that dynamic allocation be implemented with a heap. Fairy dust and unicorns are perfectly acceptable if someone can figure out how to meet the requirements laid out in the C++ Standard with them.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anybody see any pitfall on this implementation?

You've failed to align the buffer for the objects. The alignment requirement of `char` is only 1 which is not enough for most types. You need to use `alignas` to specify a stricter alignment, and you should add `alignof` validation beside the `sizeof` check.

A structured way to achieve similar could be to use `std::variant`:

```
std::variant<TwoWheeler, ThreeWheeler> vehicle;

if (type == VT_TwoWheeler) 
    v1ptr = &vehicle.emplace<TwoWheeler>();
else if (type == VT_ThreeWheeler) 
    v1ptr = &vehicle.emplace<ThreeWheeler>();
```

Bonus advice: You can perform your assertions at compile time using `static_assert`.

Comment: Would 
alignas(20) char buff[20];
be correct?

Comment: @Gust Alignments should be powers of two. You can check the alignments of the concrete classes that you will have and choose the alignas based on that. `alignas(alignof(std::max_align_t))` would be a fairly safe choice (unless you need overaligned children)

Comment: Default constructed std::variant should be used with care in this case because TwoWheeler will always be constructed. That may be not safe if constructor is not trivial, e.g. in embedded environment a kind of resource initialization can be implemented there or some heavy computations.

Comment: @EvgenyS. Good point. The factory might return the variant itself to resolve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

> #include <assert.h>

Use `#include <cassert>` in C++.

> char buff[20];

1. If you ever see a random number, you'll ask yourself why. Why `20`? Why not more? Why not less? `20` may be not enough - may be too much. It's better to calculate the value, rather then `assert` it's enough. And that `assert` is not runtime assertion - it should be a `static_assert`.
2. The buffer may not be properly aligned.
3. You did not call object destructors.

In a constrained simple environment, you may:

```
alignas(std::max(alignof(TwoWheeler), alignof(ThreeWheeler)))
    char buff[std::max(sizeof(TwoWheeler), sizeof(ThreeWheeler))];
```

But that's repetitive pattern! It's better to use an union. It's better to use an union on steroids - just `std::variant` and forget about all the unsafe manual robust `new` you did. Just:

```
#include <variant>
std::variant<std::monostate, TwoWheeler, ThreeWheeler> buff;
Vehicle *v1ptr;
int main() { 
    VehicleType type = VT_ThreeWheeler; 
    if (type == VT_TwoWheeler) {
        buff = TwoWheeler();
        v1ptr = &(std::get<TwoWheeler>(buff));
    } else if (type == VT_ThreeWheeler) {
        buff = ThreeWheeler();
        v1ptr = &(std::get<ThreeWheeler>(buff));
    }
    v1ptr->printVehicle(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk

Comment: std::variant will use default constructor in this case, i.e. TwoWheeler will always be constructed which may be not safe.

Comment: Edited with `std::monostate`.

Comment: HI @KamilCuk, you pointed "You did not call object destructors". Do I still need that if I did not dynamically allocate any memory in the class?

Comment: @Gust Yes and depends on what the destructor does. Sometimes on embedded bare matel devices that are working in a endless loop, that's irrelevant, even some projects remove destructors of static objects from memory to save space.

Comment: Hello @KamilCuk, I added a destructor to `Vehicle` class, some output messages and compiled your example (mixed with code from @eerorika ). See [here please](https://rextester.com/ACYQ88788). According to the output, the base class destructor is called twice. This seems wrong. Why is this? When I change `VehicleType type` to `VT_TwoWheeler` (which uses `emplace()` instead of `get()`) , I see only the single expected call to the destructor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `std::aligned_storage` with "placement new" in this case to be sure that objects are properly allocated. Besided, if `aligned_storage` is used with max size and max alignment of all derived classes it is expected to be used for then there is no need to check size constraints in constructors. See example below.

```cpp
// define classes somewhere above

// create buffer
std::aligned_storage_t<
   std::max(sizeof(TwoWheeler),sizeof(ThreeWheeler)),
   std::max(alignof(TwoWheeler),alignof(ThreeWheeler))
  > buff;

// use
Vehicle *v1ptr=nullptr;
int main() { 
    VehicleType type = VT_ThreeWheeler; 
    if (type == VT_TwoWheeler) 
        v1ptr = new(&buff) TwoWheeler;
    else if (type == VT_ThreeWheeler) 
        v1ptr = new(&buff) ThreeWheeler;
    v1ptr->printVehicle();

    v1ptr->~Vehicle();  
    return 0; 
}
```

UPDATE:

Don't forget to declare the destructor of the base polymorphic class `Vehicle` as virtual.

Comment: This requires you know ahead of time every possible derived types. At that point you might as well just use `std::variant`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Anyway, to use "placement new" one should know size and alignment constraints for the objects. Then, those constraints might be used in aligned_storage_t instead of the ones used in my example. And the std::variant should be used with care, as you can see in examples of other answers, they all use default constructors of std::variant which may be not safe for non-trivial constructors. Whereas std::aligned_storage_t is guaranteed to be an uninitialied storage and a constructor of desired object is invoked only once when needed.